# Ask for reference about existence of solution to a non elliptic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am considering the existence of solution to a non-elliptic PDE. For 1D problem, the equation becomes a ODE, which is of the following form:

$$\begin{cases}-a^2(x)\dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}u+b(x)\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}u+cu=f,\quad -M\le x\le M,\\ u(-M)=u(M)=0,\end{cases}$$
where $a(x)=0\iff x=0$, for example $a(x)=ax$ with $a>0$.For high dimensions, the 2nd order operator will involves mixed partial derivatives.  We can see from the 1D problem that it's not elliptic. I am interested in the existence of solution in $H^2_0(\Omega)$ for a given $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. May I know whether there is any reference you can recommend?

Comment: How is this a PDE rather than an ODE? I don't see any other variable.

Comment: @TrialAndError  Sorry. For 1D it's an ODE, but in general the 2nd order operator can involve mixed partial derivative with different components.

Comment: For the ODE you can multiply by a factor and put the equation into Sturm-Liouville form. Then you have a spectral problem, except for the singularity at $x=0$, which may require that you look separately on $[-M,0]$ and $[M,0]$. Once posed as a spectral problem, you need to know if $0$ is in the spectrum of the operator on the left. That will depend on the coefficients, and there's no general way to determine whether or not $c$ will be in the spectrum.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thanks for your response. Is there any reference you can recommend for this topic?

Comment: Zettl has a book on Sturm-Liouville Theory: http://www.amazon.com/Sturm-Liouville-Mathematical-Surveys-Monographs-Paperback/dp/B011SJIS82/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1460661387&sr=1-4